# Can anyone give an idea related to Radix Sort?

Tags: c, data-structures, radix-sort

As I'm learning Data Structures and Algorithms I came across some sorting algorithms such as this Radix Sort.
Your Ideas can help me alot.

I know what it is but the only thing i don't understand is it's implementation as we take decimal number system for integer but what if user enters  an array of binary numbers then would we be taking a bin array of binary number system.
So i wanted to solve this problem but could'nt get it .

Comment: Broad question --> board idea: perhaps [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) for some ideas?

Comment: I have found this very interesting and easy to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KhZ7F-jOlI

Comment: Try to solve it, then ask a more specific question.

Comment: *"user enters an array of binary numbers"*: a number is a number. What is a binary number? Do you mean a string representation of a number that has the binary format? Whether you use a radix of 10 or a radix of 2 is your choice. It should not have to depend on which format a user uses to represent the input numbers as text.